# Can a computer store anything that is not represented in binary code?

Tags: java

For example, how does a computer store bytecode contained in class files? Is it possible for a computer to store anything without converting it to bytecode first?

Comment: under the cover everything is 1 and 0

Comment: Only the dust over the keyboard. ;-)

Comment: Bytecode has to do with java and its compilation process so I fuese I just placed the tag accordingly since I did not know What to put

Comment: Should have tried googling.

Comment: I think you are missing the difference between native code and binary. Everything in a computer is binary but only native code (specific sequences of binary digits) is executable. But that does not mean a computer can only store executable code. It can store any binary sequences.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but it's very unusual for a digital computer to operate on anything but binary. For example, there are [ternary computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_computer)(s) which (per Wikipedia)

> a computer that uses ternary logic (three possible values) instead of the more common binary logic (two possible values) in its calculations.

Another possible example is an [analog computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_computer) which (again, per Wikipedia)

> a form of computer that uses the continuously changeable aspects of physical phenomena such as electrical, mechanical, or hydraulic quantities to model the problem being solved.

Finally, a [quantum computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computing) (to quote Wikipedia again)

> quantum computation uses quantum bits (qubits), which can be in superpositions of states

Comment: More specifically speaking about compilation processes where bytecode is generated for later execution, how does the computer store that non-binary code?

Comment: A binary computer (by definition), stores everything in binary. Bytes are composed of bits. Bits are binary 1 or 0. ASCII is one form of text representation (using binary). Ebcdic is another.

Comment: Basically, what I mean is, is bytecode stored as bytecode before compilation? Otherwise how is it stored, given a computer can only store data in 1s & 0s?

Comment: @FelipeCalderon I already answered you. For an easy to understand table see [ASCII Code](http://www.ascii-code.com/).

Answer (score -2):

No.  At the core, all data stored by computers is binary.

Comment: Thanks. Then why does everthing have to go through the JVM etc... I mean before class files are interpreted by JVM, is it already binary?